# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I need to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$ converges ($x$ is not an integer, so the denominator is never zero, also $x \in \mathbb R$).

**Proof**

$$N:=\min\{n > |x| \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$$

if I show that $\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}$, then the proof is complete.

$$N=a+|x|, \quad 0<a<1$$

$$\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(|x|+a+n)^2-x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n)(a+n+2|x|)}$$

Now because $a$ and $|x|$ are positve $\frac{1}{(a+n)(a+n+2|x|)}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+n)(a+n+2|x|)}$ converges because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ does.

Answer (score 1):

Domination of the absolute value of the general term by the general term of an absolutely convergent series is a valid criterion.

You may want to state explicitly that x is real because you are using it in your proof. The theorem is true for complex x but then you need to modify the proof.